# AEM How to package user group and permission in AEM 6

Tags: aem

I got a problem in AEM 6.1.
I created some groups in an author instance (ex: group1, group2) and assign these groups to contributor group of AEM. After that, grant some permissions (read, modify, delete in /content node) for these groups.

I would like to package these groups (include permissions) and install into other author instance.
Package node under /home/groups, /content/rep:policy and even /jcr:system/rep:permissionStore/crx.default, then install into other author instance.

Problem: In the second author instance, only have the groups. The permissions of the groups cannot installed into this instance. Need to grant permissions again.

Does anyone have a solution for this.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have to create package of all ACL to migrate from one CQ instance to another you can use xpath query for package as //element(*,rep:ACL)

see this -http://www.wemblog.com/2011/11/how-to-create-package-based-on-xpath-in.html

Also this - https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/acl-packager.html

Comment: what exactly did you try and what was the output?

Comment: I'm using AEM 6.1. Installed the lastest package (CQ5.6) in your first link (second link is broken). Run the page: http://localhost:4502/apps/tools/components/createPackage/run.html. Input '/content' in Base path, '//element(*,rep:ACL)' in Xpath, 'MyACLPackage' for package name, 'overwrite' for AC handling. After clicking on 'create config package' button, it redirects to error page (403 forbidden) - "Cannot serve request to /apps/tools/components/createPackage/run.html in /libs/sling/servlet/errorhandler/default.jsp". Thank you in advance

Comment: updated second link - https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/2014/01/20/acl-packager.html

Comment: you try to look into the code and try to figure out how they have done it. and you should be able to debug and find out why its failing in your case.

Comment: Thank you, @awadheshv. This problem was solved. When edit package, in advanced tab, I selected "Overwrite" option for AC Handling.

Answer (score 0):

Here are detailed instructions on how to migrate users, groups and permissions between AEM 6.x instances:
https://gist.github.com/andrewmkhoury/c32e6bd4e339a7c9944e0399254eb2b5

This includes the case where you need to migrate both users, groups and ACLs without installing any special tools.

Answer (score -1):

While migrating users and groups from one instance to another **crxde** is not able to override the ACL permissions of 'admin' and 'anonymous' user.

You have to exclude these from your package.

More details in below links:

http://www.tothenew.com/blog/users-migration-from-cq5-6-to-aem-6-06-1/

https://adobeaemhub.com/2016/12/31/aem-6-2-user-migration/

hope it will work.